# Acumatica restrict customers in system

Tags: acumatica

I want to build in  custom restriction in acumatica for customers. The built in access rights and features do not solve my problem.

Is it possible to add a new attribute on the customer DAC that gives me access to restrict the customers in the system.

I want to restrict the customers by branch using access rolls.

I have tried the build in feathers in acumatica explained here:
https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=90609745-18fd-4154-83f6-1d9b23c2f7a3
The problem is these restriction also blocks the warehouses that I do not want.

I know my solostion will probably be to add a attribute to the DAC?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to use Restriction Groups which is already out of the box in Acumatica. If you want a "programmable" solution, you can use the PXRestrictor Attribute and compare the current branch value (From AcceessInfo) with the Branch value in your custom field. Having said so I would suggest to use restriction groups as you can also do it at a customer class level instead of a single customer